# What does these command do in command prompt?

Tags: command-line

```
xcopy /E /V /I /F /Y "C:\Program Files (x86)\Diablo III" "H:\programs\Diablo III"
cmd /C rd /S /Q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Diablo III"
cmd /C mklink /J "C:\Program Files (x86)\Diablo III" "H:\programs\Diablo III"
```

This is what steam mover uses when moving program to another folder.

Why uses xcopy? What's wrong with regular copy or move command?

Why does `cmd /C mklink /J "C:\Program Files (x86)\Diablo III" "H:\programs\Diablo III"`

Why not just do

```
mklink /J "C:\Program Files (x86)\Diablo III" "H:\programs\Diablo III"
```

That sort of thing
Why prepend the command with `cmd /c`?

I know rd is a command. I have no idea what cmd is.

Comment: [xcopy](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html), [cmd](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html), [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)

Comment: It seems that cmd.exe is command prompt itself. Why does cmd bla bla why not go straight doing mklink /J

Comment: <shrug> No obvious reason springs to mind.

Comment: Please note that these symlinks/junctions may break when updating a program/game, leaving the program/game in an unusable state. Happened to me with Visual Studio, had to reinstall Windows because it's deeply rooted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1:** Copy everything regarding D3 from C:\program files to H:\program files

**Step 2:** Since we copied everything off of the C drive, delete the program from C:\program files

**Step 3**: Create a Symbolic link using a directory junction. This creates an alias between the 2 directories. So, if the blizzard launcher is looking for C:\program files\d3, it will be forwarded to h:\program files\d3. This step is important so that other applications do not have to look in the new place for the files.

xcopy is able to copy folder hierarchies and copy is intended for just files (usually).

So, what you have here is:

```
xcopy 
/E (Copy folders and subfolders) 
/V (Verify that the new files were written correctly) 
/I (If in doubt always assume the destination is a folder, e.g. when the destination does not exist.) 
/F (Display full source and destination file names while copying.) 
/Y (Suppress prompt to confirm overwriting a file.)
from c:\program files\d3
to h:\program files\d3
_____

cmd (Start a new CMD shell and (optionally) run a command/executable program.)
/C (Run Command and then terminate)
rd (remove directory (delete the folder we are about to specify))
/S (Delete all files and subfolders in addition to the folder itself. Use this to remove an entire folder tree.)
/Q (Quiet - do not display Y/N confirmation)
for the old game directory c:\program files\d3
______

cmd (Start a new CMD shell and (optionally) run a command/executable program.)
/C (Run Command and then terminate)
mklink (Create a symbolic link to a directory or a file, or create a hard file link or directory junction.)
/J (Create a Directory Junction.)
between C:\program files\d3 and h:\program files\d3
```

Comment: why the cmd /c?

Comment: There really is no reason for it. Not including it would yield the exact same result. It looks flashier because you get more windows to automatically open and close, but that's it.

Comment: @JimThio btw, stoked for season 6 tomorrow?

Comment: I am viewing season 5 game of throne thanks :) @narzard